# Find the occurrences of a string in a partial array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array where I fill in the types as string of each element. For example:

Types array

```
type1 | type2 | type2 | type3 | type2 | type1 | type3

$types = array('type1', 'type2', 'type2', 'type3', 'type2', 'type1', 'type3')
```

Now I want to count the occurrence of each type as I iterate the array.

For example:

when I am at the first element of the array I want to return:

```
type1 : 1
type2 : 0
type3 : 0
```

When I am at the fourth element I want:

```
type1 : 1
type2 : 2
type3 : 1
```

Actually, I am only interested to find the occurrence of the type of the element which I am looking. For example: `fourth element`

```
type3: 1
```

Is there a php function to do that? Or I will have to iterate the whole array and count the occurrences of types ?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of using pseudo code syntax, use a real php array.

Comment: Nothing yet I am asking if there is a php function to do that. I know how to do that but I believe it is now efficient. I would provide php code now.

Comment: are these types are *Data Types* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a native function to do this. But we can write a simple one:

```
$items = array(
        'type1',
        'type2',
        'type2',
        'type3',
        'type2',
        'type1',
        'type3'
    );

    foreach ($items as $order => $item) {
        $previous = array_slice($items, 0, $order + 1, true);
        $counts = array_count_values($previous);

        echo $item . ' - ' . $counts[$item] . '<br>';
    }
```

This code produces this:

```
type1 - 1
type2 - 1
type2 - 2
type3 - 1
type2 - 3
type1 - 2
type3 - 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I've understand your question perfectly,but If you want to count all the values of an array you can use [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) function:

```
<?php
 $array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
 print_r(array_count_values($array));
?> 

The above example will output:
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct solution:

```
$index = 4;
$array = array('type1', 'type2', 'type2', 'type3', 'type2', 'type1', 'type3')
var_dump( array_count_values( array_slice( $array, 0, $index)));
```

If you use `array_slice` to grab a section of the array, then run it to `array_count_values`, you can in effect count the values of a sub-array. So, for any `$index`, you can count the values from `0` to `$index`.

This outputs:

```
array(3) { ["type1"]=> int(1) ["type2"]=> int(2) ["type3"]=> int(1) }
```